# How to fill the area between two independent curves in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, fill, curves

I am ploting two different lines meaning that each of them have a different list for Y axis values and X axis values. How can I fill the area between them if the X axis values are different?

Let's say I have the lists for every axis for every curve:

- listXcurve1
- listYcurve1
- listXcurve2
- listYcurve2

I am trying to use fill_between, but the function is asking for:
ax.fill_between(x,y1,y2)

Is there anyway to do it?

Comment: This is of course not the first time this is asked in SO. What have you tried, in how far did it fail?

Comment: The question is: what do I have to put in every parameter in ax.fill_between(x,y1,y2)? as I just said, I have 2 different lists for x values, trying with both of them for the x does not fill anything.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask